# GPU temperature reads 88 C when training a LSTM on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, lstm, temperature, recurrent-neural-network

I've got a 1 layer LSTM model in tensorflow and the temperature reading of my GPU gets rather high during the training phase. Always varying between 80 C and 90 C. My GPU is a water cooled gtx 1080 "Super-clocked" edition in a 24/7 refrigerated room. The model works, but this temperature worries me. **I'd like to know if this is normal and safe.**

I'm training the LSTM for a next-word-prediction problem with tokenized reddit comments. I got the idea from different tutorials in wildml.com. Here are some details about it:

- Tensorflow 1.2.1, Cuda tk 8.0, Cudnn 6.0, Nvidia Driver 375.66
- My training data consists of 200 K reddit comments.
- My word dictionary consists of 8000 words, which means 8000 classes of classification for each prediction
- I use GLOVE pre-trained 100 Dimensions embeddings of Wikipedia words
- I'm not using placeholders to feed my input. It's all done with TFRecordfiles readers, which input the examples to a 100k capacity random shuffle queue
- From the random shuffle queue, it goes to a padding FIFO queue, where I generated zero-paddaded mini-batches of 20
- The 20 size mini batches go to a tf.dynamic_rnn() with LSTM cell with Hidden dimension of 150
- I mask the losses using tf.sign() and minimize the result with Adam optimizer

I've noticed that the temperature rises a lot when I raise the mini-batch size. 1 size mini-batches (single examples), it reads between 72-75 C. With 10 size mini-batches, it immediately goes to 78 C and stays in the range of 78-84 C. With 20 size mini-batches, 84-88 C. With 30 size mini-batches, 87-92 C.

If I raise the hidden dimension to 200,  250, 300, etc, while maintaining the minibatch size fixed, I also get similar temperature raises.

I've also trained the same model, but feeding the data with placeholders only, i.e, not using TFRecord, Queues and mini-batches. It stays around 65 C, but it's obviously far from optimized and ideal to use placeholders for feeding the net.

I really appreciate your help, I'm kinda desperate, to be honest.

-----------------EDIT---------------------

It turns out the water cooler pump was configured on my bios to variate according to the CPU temp...Obviously the GPU temp wouldn't affect it and thats what happened. It was running on 50 % of its capacity. Well, I've ajusted it to stay 100% all the time and now the same model runs with max temp of approx. 83 C. Still not perfect, but a huge improvement. I guess that with the complexity of my model + the really high 1.8 GHz clock of my GPU there's not much I can do.

Comment: Strange. 80+ degrees would be normal without any water cooling. My 980 Ti with water cooling under full load goes only to ~42 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum design temperature of the GTX 1080 [according to nvidia](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1080/specifications) is 94 C. Anything below that and you should be safe.

> Maximum GPU Temperature (in C)    94

The fact that the GPU temperature rises when you raise the mini-batch sizes is a good sign, this means that your GPU is working as hard as it can. In fact, if your GPU is not at ~80-90 C, this means that it is not working at full power, and you are losing some performance.